# Google login setting cognito user to not_verified when linked

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm having this issue where when I login for the first time via google email `is_verified` attribute in cognito is marked as verified after linking social account with user login. When I log out and log back in it marks email as not verified. I need it to always be verified because when it's set to not verified and I try and login  via user form instead of Google then I have to set my password in order to login that way since I sent cognito a `adminSetUserPasswordCommand` (aws-sdk v3) when linking accounts so user has to go through reset password to create their password since it was set automatically to link accounts during initial account creation process, but it won't send me the password reset code via email unless `is_verified` is true

I'm setting `is_verified` to true at end of `PreSignUp_ExternalProvider` event for initial linking of accounts which works for initial signup. It's the subsequent logins via Google that are the issue.

PreSignUp_ExternalProvider event trigger

```
export async function signUpLambda(event, context: Context) {
  console.log("event type: ", event.triggerSource);
  console.log("signup event", event);

  const { triggerSource, userPoolId, userName, request } = event;
  const {
    userAttributes: { email, given_name, family_name },
  } = request;

  if (triggerSource === "PreSignUp_ExternalProvider") {

    const aliasName = request.userAttributes["cognito:email_alias"];
    const user = await findUserByEmail(email, userPoolId);
    console.log("user found for some reason", user);


    let [providerName, providerUserId] = userName.split("_");

    providerName = providerName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + providerName.slice(1);

    //   // if the user is found then we link the Google account to the user pool
    if (user) {
      const test = {
        userPoolId: userPoolId,
        cognitoUsername: user.Username,
        providerName: providerName,
        providerUserId: providerUserId,
      };

      try {
        await linkSocialAccount(
          userPoolId,
          user.Username,
          providerName,
          providerUserId
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR LINKING ACCOUTNS", err);
      }
      return event;
    } else {
      // 1. create a native cognito account
      const newUser = await createUser(userPoolId, email, aliasName);
      if (!newUser) {
        throw new Error("Failed to create user");
      }

      // 2. change the password, to change status from FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD to CONFIRMED
      await setSystemGeneratedUserToTrue(email);
      await setUserPassword(userPoolId, email);

      // 3. merge the social and the native accounts and set account to confirmed
      await setEmailVerifiedToTrue(email);
    }
  }

  return event;
}
```

and it works for the most part except for when I log out and log back in via google it changes verified to not verified.

I have no idea why subsequent google logins are changing it to `not verified`. I currently have to call `await setEmailVerifiedToTrue(email);` when logging in via google to keep account confirmed otherwise in cognito console it says `not verified` after logging in.

So to recap step by step:

`Step 1`

I create a new account via google login

￼[image]

`Step 2`

Now if I log out and log back in you will see that the email is no longer verified upon logging back in which is what triggers it to not verified.  
￼
[image]

It works when logging into Google every time, but if the user wants to login via user forms at another time in the future instead of social provider like Google since account is linked then they have to go through the forgot password because when they first created an account via google login, I set the password for the user to make this work via
await setUserPassword(userPoolId, email); so the user doesn’t know the password.

[image]
￼

The problem with this is that in order to receive the password reset code in their email the account has to be verified. I don't want to have to call this function everytime a user logs in.

```
export async function setEmailVerifiedToTrue(email: string) {
  const params = {
    UserPoolId: USER_POOLID,
    Username: email,
    UserAttributes: [
      {
        Name: "email_verified",
        Value: "true",
      },
    ],
  };

  try {
    const command = new AdminUpdateUserAttributesCommand(params);
    await cognito.send(command);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error updating user attributes", e);
  }
}
```

It seems overkill and a waste of cognito sync operations. So I'm looking for maybe a solution or something I might be missing to avoid that. I appreciate any help!

Comment: The question doesn't really read coherently to me - can you please post step by step instructions of what you're doing, the actual output and the expected output? How are you trying to log back in the second time?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I've updated my post and have added steps of issue. Thanks!